# ASP Classic - every property/method of response object but write generates error

Tags: asp-classic, response

So we have this ASP Classic application which we moved to a new shared hosting server running Windows 2008. 
now EVERY call to response methods or any access to it's properties generates **"Object doesn't support this property or method"** error. the only thing that works is **response.write** which puzzles me more. 
tech support says there is nothing wrong with this server and that thy have "many other asp classics applications working smoothly" 
what's going on?

**EDIT:** here's the code I use to preform the test

```
<%
on error resume next

'clear method -----------------------------------------------------------------
response.Clear  
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "Clear: <U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

'properties -------------------------------------------------------------------
response.write  "<br />Cookies: "  
response.Cookies("test") = "testing" 'does not produce any output
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Buffer: "
response.write response.Buffer  
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />CacheControl: "
response.write response.CacheControl
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Charset: "
response.write response.Charset
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />ContentType: "
response.write response.ContentType 
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Expires: "
response.write response.Expires 
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />ExpiresAbsolute: "
response.write response.ExpiresAbsolute 
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />IsClientConnected: "
response.write response.IsClientConnected   
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Pics: "
response.Pics = ""
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Status: "
response.write response.Status  
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

' methods ---------------------------------------------------------------------
response.write  "<br />AddHeader: "
response.AddHeader  "testheader","testheadervalue"
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />AppendToLog: "
response.AppendToLog    ""
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />BinaryWrite: "
response.BinaryWrite    "B"
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Flush: "
response.Flush  
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if

response.write  "<br />Write: "
response.Write  "W"
if err<>0 then 
    response.write "<U>ASPCheck-ErroR " & err.description & "</U>"
    err.clear
end if
%>
```

and here is the result:

```
Clear: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Cookies: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Buffer: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
CacheControl: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Charset: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
ContentType: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Expires: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
ExpiresAbsolute: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
IsClientConnected: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Pics: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Status: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
AddHeader: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
AppendToLog: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
BinaryWrite: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Flush: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method
Write: W
```

Comment: can you paste some code not working?

Comment: I run your code on my server and the only error that i get is:

Pics: ASPCheck-ErroR Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: yup, exactly. same as my dev machine, but not on server

Comment: Is it possible ASP hasn't been installed correctly?

Comment: Well, Hard to find out, It's a shared hosting server. It looks like some sort of security limitation to me. or maybe they have something else installed that causes this behaviuor.

Answer (score 0):

On IIS, `enable buffering` is uncheched.

You can find this setting under Application Development > ASP > Enable Buffering.

Comment: No. that would explain some errors, but what about things like Buffer, CacheControl, Charset, ContentType, Expires, ExpiresAbsolute, IsClientConnected and Status? tried that though.